# Laravel all routes except '/' return 404 on AWS EC2

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run Laravel project on AWS EC2. It was working fine until uploaded a new version to deploy. All routes return error 404 except for '/' though all routes exist. httpd.conf in /etc/httpd/conf contains this

```
<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I always execute these commands after deploying a new version

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/app/current
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/app/current
```

I tried "sudo a2enmod rewrite" but I get "sudo: a2enmod: command not found"

Any solution?

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: How did you deploy? If you were able to navigate other routes before publishing, you shouldn't have to change anything with Apache.

Comment: using elastic beanstalk upload and deploy

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the instance and re-deploying the app solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

After modifying /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

You need to also restart httpd using **sudo service httpd restart**

Refer to [Laravel ReST API URL 404 not found on AWS EC2 in Apache + mySQL environment - The request URL was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891736/laravel-rest-api-url-404-not-found-on-aws-ec2-in-apache-mysql-environment-th/)